# Flutter project not opening on ios simulator problem

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, firebase

I want to run my flutter app in ios and I also configure some files like this:

My PodFile platform ios target: 11.0 and pods like that:

```
...
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.3.0'
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
...
```

My AppDelegate file :

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseCore

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure() 
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

My flutter pubs:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_animated_splash: ^0.0.10
  google_fonts: ^4.0.1
  custom_navigation_bar: ^0.8.2
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.8
  firebase_core: ^2.6.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.2
  google_sign_in: ^6.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.1.2
  unicons: ^2.1.0
  lottie: ^2.2.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.4
  zego_uikit_prebuilt_call: ^1.4.2
  zego_uikit_signaling_plugin: ^1.4.1
  badges: ^3.0.2
  flutter_number_picker: ^1.0.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
```

My Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

This is what i was faced problem [image]

And click Reopen button show this
[image]

Also I would like to say, I uploaded this GoogleService-Info.plist file with Xcode(Add File to Runner)

Comment: firebabse did not be able to detect googleservice-info.plist file
use flutterfire to configure firebase it automatically configrue all things for you

Comment: I test it but still showing same problem. A new flutter project running perfectly, but when i add firebase or other dependencies then faced this problem

Comment: And I want like to say , i also tested a create new flutter project and integrate my dart files in there and configure all ios settings , pods, pubs and all